# Label rotation not working in Titanium

Tags: rotation, label, titanium, transform

In the following code, I want to first rotate the label by 270 degree, set the anchor point and then again rotate it by a certain angle.

However, only the second rotation works and the first rotation is ignored. How can I solve this ?

```
var myLabels = [];
for (var i=0; i < 26; i++) {

var singleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    backgroundColor:'red',
    text: i+1,
    top: 100,
    width: 35,
    height:20,

});
  var rotateFirst = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(270);

singleLabel.transform = rotateFirst;

    singleLabel.setAnchorPoint({x: 0.5,y:11.11});
    var rotate1 = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate((13.84*i));;

   singleLabel.transform = rotate1;
   myLabels.push(singleLabel);
   view.add(singleLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use animations instead of setting the transform property.

You can chain them using the animation start / complete events